# CSS Sticky Bar Overlapping

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I am using the Sticky Footer code from [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) and for some reason the sticky footer overlaps my .content class on my site.

My site: http://tangotest.comoj.com

As you can see the 910x50px image at the bottom overlaps the white box when you scroll to the bottom on any given page.

I need the 910x50px image to be at the bottom of the white box when you scroll to the bottom.

CSS for the white box .content class

```
.content {
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
background: white;
}
```

CSS for the Sticky Footer .player class

```
.player {
position: fixed;
left: 470px;
bottom: 0px;
height: 50px;
width: 50%;
background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try increasing the padding of the page body.

Currently it is:

```
body {
background-image: url('http://tangoworldwide.net/Themes/Altier_2/images/tango/city01.jpg');
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
```

}

try changing the padding-bottom to

```
padding-bottom: 30px;
```

Comment: Wish I thought of this before. Thanks, it's now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
.player {
position: relative;
left: 200px;
bottom: 20px;
height: 50px;
width: 50%;
background: transparent;
}
```

is this what you want? if not this.

```
.player {
position: fixed;
left: 200px;
bottom: 0px;
height: 50px;
width: 50%;
background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set margin-bottom to footer:

Any margin greater than 10px will do:

```
    .footer {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        background: white;
    }
```

to increase further gap between white div and fixed bottom div you can increase margin-bottom to greater values.